# Jquery Ajax error: code：19 message：Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have two web apps in the same domain with different ports, e.g.:

- http://test.com:8888
- http://test.com:8787

One is used to edit content, one is used to show content.

When I open the two websites in the same browser at the same time, i edit the content and save it with AJAX post request，It always fails with this error：

```
code：19  message：Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest'  name: "NetworkError"
```

Please tell me what's happened and how to fix it. Thanks！

Comment: I think XMLHttpRequest needs to be the same everything; so domain, port, etc.

Answer (score 0):

From W3:

> An origin is defined as a combination of URI scheme, hostname, and
>   port number.

The port is the problem.  You'll have to investigate other alternatives, such as JSONP for example.